# How to load the next file while current one is playing through HTTP Live Streaming?

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, avplayer, http-live-streaming, avqueueplayer

I'm working on an app in which I need to stream a large collection of audio files ranging from 5 to 15 seconds each.
I would like to reduce the load time between the files as much as possible.

Main Question:
**Is there a way to start buffering the next file (through HLS) while the current one is playing the last segment?**

Is AVQueuePlayer an appropriate solution for this on the iOS side?

A detailed explanation will be much appreciated, since I am new both to HTTP Live Streaming and the AV Foundation.

Related Question:
How do radio apps stream their audio with no lag between the songs?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `AVQueuePlayer` is an appropriate solution for playing a sequence of audio streamed from the internet via HTTP protocol.

I'm using `AVQueuePlayer` for quite a while now with excellent results and no lagging between songs. Here is a simple example on how to use `AVQueuePlayer`:

```
NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlsToPlay objectAtIndex:0]];
NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlsToPlay objectAtIndex:1]];
NSURL *url3 = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlsToPlay objectAtIndex:2]];

self.item1 = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:url1];
self.item2 = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:url2];
self.item3 = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:url3];

self.radioPlayerURLs = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.item1,self.item2, self.item3, nil];
self.onDemandPlayer  = [AVQueuePlayer queuePlayerWithItems:self.radioPlayerURLs];
[self.onDemandPlayer play];
```

For more details, please consulte Apple documentation:

[AVFoundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html)

[AVQueuePlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVQueuePlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVQueuePlayer)